Is there a way to get the latitude & longitude for a county in the U.S. using Azure Maps?
A fair number of the users of my app do not want to provide their address. But they are ok with providing their county & state (no zip code). I use their location to provide them with events near them. So I need to get the latitude & longitude of the center (or center-ish) point of that county.
I use Azure Maps. Is there a call in Azure Maps to pass in a "county, state" and get back the location?
I use MapsSearchClient.SearchAddress("1 Main St., Anytown, CO, 80000") if I have an address.
I use:
var address = new StructuredAddress()
{
    PostalCode = zipCode,
    CountryCode = "US"
};
var result = await SearchClient.SearchStructuredAddressAsync(address);

If I only have a zip code.
Is there some way to use StructuredAddress if all I have is county, state, and "US"?

You will get an HTML response from the server with a map.  The HTML contains a tag with location that will contain longitude and latitude.  So you can use an HTML parse to search for the tag location in the HTML.  If you use a browser you can use the developer tools to see the html and search for location to see if the longitude and latitude is on the map response.

@jdweng I added more info to show how I'm calling it. It returns JSON for an address check.

You are running a java script on the HTML map that is returning JSON. geolocation is using an HTML map.  See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-geolocation

@jdweng There is no HTML involved here. They are using Azure Maps, not Google Maps, big difference. The search client they are referencing is a client library for calling the Azure Maps REST services.

I removed the C# and geolocation tags as those generic tags were likely drawing people in who where downvoting this.

@rbrundritt Why did you remove the tags c# and geolocation?  The OP wants Latitude and Longitude.  Geolocation will give Latitude and Longitude.

@jdweng they want latitude and longitude from the Azure Maps platform using C#. The C# geolocation API is not available in all .NET applications (only client apps such as those that run on Windows or Maui). They misused the word "geolocation" when they meant "geocode". I have been working with this user for a while.

@rbrundritt Out of curiosity what's the difference between geolocation & geocode? Is it geocode is specifically lat/long while geolocation is more broadly where something is (i.e. also address, etc.)?

The term "Geolocation" is typically used for the scenario where a users location is retrieved from a sensor, like a GPS. Windows, Android, IOS all expose a geolocation API that lets you use the built in sensor. Some of these return information with the location, such as city and state.
Geocoding however is the process of taking address or place information (string) and looking up the most likely location that should appear on a map (latitude/longitude).

Note that the Client libraries for Azure Maps are in "prerelese" state and are regularly being updated. Most notable is that Azure Maps has newer search services for geocoding, reverse geocoding, and boundary retrieval. If you get the latest version of this client library you will find that the SearchStructuredAddressAsync method no longer exists as that is from the old search services, had access to less data, and was generally less accurate than the latest geocoding service. Here is how you would use the latest version of that library to retrieve a county result.
Response<GeocodingResponse> searchResult = client.GetGeocoding("", new Azure.Maps.Search.Models.Queries.GeocodingQuery()
{
    AdminDistrict2 = "King", //County
    AdminDistrict = "WA", //State
    CountryRegion = "US"
});


Thank you, for the answer and removing the C# tag. Is this the documentation for the latest version? TIA

Yes, that looks like the latest docs.

As always, thank you
